# IOS Firebase Cloud Messaging "InvalidApnsCredential"

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add push notifications to my Ionic app using FCM and running into issues with IOS, (android works as intended). Before marking this as a duplicate, Ive tried the solutions from the other similar questions but it didnt help.

In the firebase console I have set the team Id, App id as well as uploded the APNS p5 generated by apple to my console as well.

And finally, the latest plist file to my app's root. From xcode, I can see the certificate has push notifications enabled too and the app asks for that permission for it as well. After that I got the device notification id and tested it via the console as well as the api endpoint but I keep getting the "InvalidApnsCredential" error. I did the steps from few other questions from here but had no luck. I cant seem to get it working, below is a few snippets of my code

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.fcmService.getToken().then(resp=>{
                this.httpService.sendToken(resp)
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        console.log(res)
                    });
                console.log(resp)
            });
        });
```

And the body of the api post request

```
Endpoint: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Body:
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Ionic 4 Notification",
    "body":"This notification sent from POSTMAN using Firebase HTTP protocol",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
  "data":{
    "landing_page":"second",
    "price":"$3,000.00"
  },
    "to":"IOS_DEVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID",
    "priority":"high",
    "restricted_package_name":""
}
```

The code and api endpoint seems correct as it works for Android. Is there anything im missing to get it working?

Comment: did you try before fcmService.getToken() to launch get permission?

Comment: So, I deleted the IOS app from firebase and re created it and it seems to be working. A bit odd but I didn't change any code!

Comment: Mysterious but the good part its working .

Comment: yeah hopefully it was one time error and doesnt break again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this may not be exactly the answer that youre looking for but, for me everything worked fine after i recreated the app on ios. 
Common issues include 
- trying to send a notification before the client gives premission
- sending notifications using older IDs (yes they change sometimes)
- package name mismatch between your app and ios app

Answer (score 0):

Following are the reasons of "InvalidApnsCredential":

1. Maybe bundle id changed [find in code where bundle id name mismatch, change it]
2. APN keys expired [ update it in firebase console]
3. Find out the exact error from this link [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that you got.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to enter and upload the `APNs Authentication Key` in the firebase console. Please go to the

> - Cloud Messaging -> Apple app configuration

Add AuthKey File(.p8), Key Id & Team ID

Check the image below. And it's working fine for me.

Make sure `Team ID` is added in the SDK setup and configuration.

[image]